# How to align card-desk center of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need solve problem to align card-desk to center of page for large screen. I'm using Bootstrap 4.
My current code here https://jsbin.com/faheheboxu/edit?html,css,output

I used .container for flex, card-desk with cards in flex container, but don't know how align card-desk center vertically.

Tried to use absolute height and wight,and also padding. But it ruined flex with small screens

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row align-self-center">
            <div class="col-12 align-self-center">
            <div class="card-deck mb-3 mt-3 text-center">
                <div class="card box-shadow">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="nice_house.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-normal">Best house</h4> 
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p1>Blablabla</p1>
                </div>   
                </div>
                <div class="card box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="common_house.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-normal">Common house</h4> 
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Blablabla</p>
                    <a href="nice_flat.html" class="btn btn-primary">See more</a>
                </div>   
                </div>
                <div class="card box-shadow">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="worst_house.jpg" alt="Card image cap">  
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-normal">Worst house</h4> 
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p1>Blablabla</p1>
                </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Keplian You just need to add `h-100` to the first div & `mx-auto` to the second div in your html like so:

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row align-self-center mx-auto">
    <div class="col-12 align-self-center">
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 mt-3 text-center">
        <div class="card box-shadow">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="nice_house.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="font-weight-normal">Best house</h4> 
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p1>Blablabla</p1>
          </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="card box-shadow">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="common_house.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="font-weight-normal">Common house</h4> 
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Blablabla</p>
            <a href="nice_flat.html" class="btn btn-primary">See more</a>
          </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="card box-shadow">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="worst_house.jpg" alt="Card image cap">  
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="font-weight-normal">Worst house</h4> 
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p1>Blablabla</p1>
          </div>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It'll center the cards horizontally. Then, you must add this to your css file:

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You'll find the cards horizontally & vertically center now.

You can find a working **sample code [here](https://jsbin.com/bemitiduha/1/edit?html,output).**